# MjpegProcessor dont work in console application context

Tags: c#, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have a problem with the `MjpegProcessor` Library. In my c# console application the `Mjpeg_FrameReady` method is never called.
If I debug the application, the stream is open, but nothing happens in the console.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using MjpegProcessor;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Server
{
    internal class StreamHandler
    {
        private MjpegDecoder _mjpeg;

        public StreamHandler()
        {
            Thread handler = new Thread(StartHandler);
            handler.Start();
        }

        private void StartHandler()
        {
            _mjpeg = new MjpegDecoder();
            _mjpeg.FrameReady += Mjpeg_FrameReady;
            _mjpeg.Error += Mjpeg_Error;
            _mjpeg.ParseStream(new Uri("http://172.0.0.1/mjpg/video.mjpg"), "edv", "edv1bkt");
        }

        private void Mjpeg_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        private void Mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap image = e.Bitmap;           

            Console.WriteLine(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Does it need a windows forms context?

Comment: You are writing an image to the console using write line, does that even compile?

Comment: Yes, it calls the `ToString` Method. That's the convertible part...